# Cryptography hex,binaries and ascii python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am new to cryptography and when it comes to xor I get really confused.
Given a text in ascii and a cipher in hex how can I get them to be both in the same format?
My current code is:

```
import binascii
string = b'09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36'
binary = binascii.unhexlify(string)
#This make the hex string to raw bytes
```

My question is how can I get an ascii string to be in raw bytes also so I can xor?
or if it is not possible what should I do to xor?

Comment: *"This make the hex string to binary"*; no, it will (per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify)) *"Return the hexadecimal representation of the binary data."*. What do you mean by *"get an ascii string to be in binary"*?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I explain better the problem, I must xor a plain text in ascii and a cipher in hex, I need them both in the same format so I can xor. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

ascii is simply a byte string

```
XOR_WITH = 0x12

def xor_encode(byte):
    if isinstance(byte,basestring):
        byte = ord(byte) #convert to ascii integer value
    byte = byte ^ XOR_WITH #encode
    return chr(byte) # convert it back to a string and return

encoded_string = "".join(map(xor_encode,"Test String"))
```

maybe what you are looking for